# Any tool is required for automatic entry in .Net application

Tags: .net

I am using a .NET Application in my office.After delivery of products each item id is submitted in delivery module.A single entry normally takes 3 mouse clicks.

In case of large lists of entries it becomes very difficult.I need some tool to automate this data entry process.So that I provide a list of item ids and it automatically feed them into application.
Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more precise? Your question is too broad and thus is difficult to answer.

Comment: Maybe a tool similar to this would help:http://www.wintask.com/automate-data-entry.php?gclid=CIHQtpnjgsYCFUzItAodoVgAkw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at AutoIt. It's propably what you want.

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

It's good in simulating keystrokes and mouse movements but it's not limited to it. It has a easy to learn syntax so it's suitable for users who are not very experienced with coding.

Comment: If you like this answer I would be happy if you mark it as accepted and/or upvote it on left side of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used both WinAutomation http://www.winautomation.com/ and vTask http://www.vtaskstudio.com/index.php in the past for automations. Both work fine, as will, I am sure, any of the other automation applications on the market. Both products will handle your automation need easily. I think vTask works a little better with desktop automation while WinAutomation is really rich on the web-automation side. You can't really go wrong with either product.